# How to show an integer value on a progress bar in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, progress-bar

I have a variable named riskIndex and it can take on values from (0-8). I want to use a progress bar to show the value of this variable. I already have a code for the progress bar and I am not sure how to connect the above-mentioned variable to the code. The existing solutions on the internet seem to implement an animated progress bar and I am not sure if I should be using it, as the variable I am using will not be updating its value. It will have a fixed value on every run. For instance, in this example, I have taken its value to be 4.

I want to show this value 4 as progress on the progress bar.

The code for the progress bar is as follows

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Animated,Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

export default function Progressbar() {
  
let riskIndex=6; 
  
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.progressLabels}>
        <Text style={styles.progressLabel}>Low</Text>
        {/* <View style={styles.progressLabel}></View>
        <Text style={styles.progressLabel}>Amateur</Text> */}
        <View style={styles.progressLabel}></View>
        <Text style={styles.progressLabel}>Moderate</Text>
        <View style={styles.progressLabel}></View>
        <Text style={styles.progressLabel}>High</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.progressContainer}>
        <LinearGradient colors={["rgb(15, 25, 75)", "rgb(90, 95, 160)"]} style={styles.progress}/>
        <View style={styles.milestonesContainer}>
          <View style={styles.milestone}/><View style={styles.milestone}/><View style={styles.milestone}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#132542',
    padding: 8,
    
  },

  progressLabels: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    width: "100%",
    marginBottom: 10,
    
  },
  progressLabel: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    //fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    width: "19%",
    textAlign: "center",
    color:'white',
    flexWrap:'wrap'
  },

  progressContainer: {
    position: "relative",
    height: 100
  },
  progress: {
    marginLeft: "5%",
    marginTop: 5,
    width: "90%",
    height: 30,
    // backgroundColor: "rgb(7, 14, 60)",
    borderRadius: 15
  },

  milestonesContainer: {
    marginLeft: "5%",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  milestone: {
    height: 40,
    width: "30%",
    //backgroundColor: "white",
    borderColor: "rgb(7, 11, 55)",
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
  }
});
```

The output of this code looks like
[image: Progress Bar Output with the above code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have riskIndex value from 0-10, just to make math simply. Your style milestone is showing progress with white background. All this style needs is to pass percentage of width. I wrote you answer without testing so maybe few tweaks need to be done.

```
riskIndex_passed = 8;
riskPerc = 8 * 10; // from 0-10, 8 is 80% of 10
riskPerc = riskPerc.toString() + "%"; // convert to string and add % at end 

<View style={styles.milestonesContainer}>
    <View style={[styles.milestone, {width: riskPerc}]} />
</View>
```

in StyleSheet I removed width and uncommented backgroundColor

```
milestone: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderColor: "rgb(7, 11, 55)",
    borderLeftWidth: 1,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
}
```